# WP Super Cache to create a static version of the full site

Tags: wordpress, caching, gulp, assets

I'm working on a WP project where the live site can't use WP (for security reasons). My solution was to build the site on a local server using WP, then export a static snapshot of the site (using WP Super Cache) that can be uploaded to the live server.

I have a [gulp](/questions/tagged/gulp) script to package the entire site:

1. Get the static files generated by WP Super Cache
2. Copy all assets (images, uploads, etc).
3. Copy other necessary files like `.htaccess`.

**Problem**

When using WP Super Cache I've noticed pages are missing from Super Cache. For example, my site has 82 pages but my cache contains only 65.

What are the settings in WP Super Cache so the entire site is cached into the WP Super Cache directory?

Or, is there another plugin better suited for caching all the pages?

Comment: I find this topic quite interesting, so let me ask you something: How/Why is security in this case such a big problem? I mean, you can put the website on a server where nothing else is running and close it down and everything. But having WP locally and then exporting static duplicates of each site seems like a lot of work to me (even if it´s automated) and not really comfortable.

Comment: I do not want to forestall Bretts answer but here is my take nonetheless: Even if you do everything to close down the server, vulnerabilities will still exist in PHP, in WP and in installed plugins. If this is a site that does not need PHP (no search etc.) there is no reason to host WP in production. Given that a clean dev process involves seperate dev and production environments anyway, creating an optimized version of the site is just a simple part of the deployment process. Also: There is a huge(!) speed gain in serving plain html files over a WP install.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a caching plugin (or any other plugin) for this as they are not made for this purpose and would need (extensive) modification not only now, but also down the road when the plugin gets updates.

I did exactly what you are planning, on a larger scale of a couple of thousand Wordpress sites. I deployed those sites statically - also for security reasons -  with a PHP script that does essentially this:

1. Get a static version with `wget` (you will need some parameters for recursion, attachment rewriting etc.)
2. Modify anything you need in the html files (you could use `sed` for this).
3. Copy assets (depending on your needs and on the `wget` configuration)

With a tool like grunt you could even run more tasks, like minification, uglification and image compression once you finished creating the static copy.

Comment: I started looking into this option last night - using Gulp to grab all the pages, etc, etc. What did you use to grab the full list of URLs for the site?

Comment: You can just use wget for that. It will spider all pages / urls by following links, you can also set a max depth.